# How to SASSify this?

Tags: angularjs, sass

I can't seem to use SASS here with a solution that manages to be more readable and with less code. I was hoping someone more experienced could help. These are classes used by angularJS's animation library. I've tried various tactics using @extend but they're either too wordy or just break the functionality. I was fiddling with nesting for a while before remembering that the space in CSS is important.

```
.container.ng-enter, 
.container.ng-leave{
  -webkit-transition :0.5s ease all;
  transition         :0.5s ease all;

  position           :absolute;
  left               :0;
  right              :0;
  height             :600px;
}

.container.ng-enter {
  z-index :100;
  left    :600px;
  opacity :0;
}
.container.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}

.container.ng-leave {
  z-index:101;
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}
.container.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:-600px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code exactly?  Have you tried looking at the Sass documentation?

Comment: I feel like it isn't very DRY, can SASS do nothing here? I've looked at the documentation and tried writing some methods using extensions and inheritance but it's tricker than it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a nice way to "SASSify" your CSS it would compile
to your above CSS.

Check out the compiled and sass versions [**here**](https://gist.github.com/davidchase/9679444).

Documentation is [**here**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

`%` is simply a place holder so this case its abstracted code that you can `@extend`

and it wont be rendered into css.

`&` is a reference to parent selector so you will get

`.container.ng-enter` instead of `.container .ng-enter`

```
%transition {
  -webkit-transition :0.5s ease all;
  transition         :0.5s ease all;
  position           :absolute;
  left               :0;
  right              :0;
  height             :600px;
}

.container {
  &.ng-enter {
    @extend %transition;
    z-index :100;
    left    :600px;
    opacity :0;
    &.ng-enter-active {
     left:0;
     opacity:1;
    }
  }
  &.ng-leave {
   @extend %transition;
   z-index:101;
   left:0;
   opacity:1;
   &.ng-leave-active {
    left:-600px;
    opacity:0;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm..I see how it's drier but it actually seems more cluttered and less readable than the plain CSS. The & sign has some pretty cool functionality though. Maybe this is a situation where Sass doesn't really help out that much.

Comment: @user2483724 I know what you mean, but for me its actually easier to read than CSS I guess I am just used to using SASS...

Comment: Ah well, at least we can have them both b/c of .scss!